# What's the difference between 'ruby script/destroy model' and 'rails destroy model'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the difference between `ruby script/destroy model` and `rails destroy model`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference, only that `script/destroy` is Rails 2 and `rails destroy` is Rails 3.

In Rails 3 all the separate scripts were removed and replaced with the single `rails` script, which accepts all the different commands that used to be in separate scripts. In this case `destroy` is the opposite to `generate` - it deletes all the generated files.

Answer (score 1):

the former is the 2.* syntax, the later the 3.* syntax. See http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#script-replaced-by-script-rails